# How to build a HATEOAS link when using a model attribute?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have a Spring `@RestController` producing `application/hal+json`. Normally I would return a `Resource` with `Link`s created by `ControllerLinkBuilder`. When I use `@RequestParam` for all query parameters passed one by one to the mapped method this works perfectly.

For a search endpoint with multiple filtering options I created a POJO containing all options as properties and Spring automatically puts all matching query parameters into that object, cool. I can even do bean validation on that object if needed:

```
@GetMapping("objects")
Resource<?> fetchObjects(@Validated Query query) {
  ...
  return new Resource(..., linkTo(methodOn(getClass()).fetchObjects(query));
}
```

But the link builder does not do the reverse mapping and so no query parameters are added.

Is there any elegant way without replacing the query object by all of its members in the signature? The only way I found so far is (a little hacky from my point):

```
private Link createQueryLink(Query query) {
   UriComponentsBuilder link = linkTo(methodOn(getClass()).fetchObjects(query))
    .toUriComponentsBuilder();
  Optional.ofNullable(query.getFoo()).ifPresent(foo -> link.queryParam("foo", foo));
  ...
  return new Link(link.build().toUriString(), Link.REL_SELF);
}
```

PS: I am using Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266366/spring-boot-hateoas-controllerlinkbuilder-linkto-query-parameter-missing

Comment: seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/496